# Clojure — Meaning of pound symbol?

Tags: syntax, clojure, clojurescript, om

In the Om Next Quick Start, they use `#js` and `#uuid`. What does the pound symbol here mean?

Link: https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Quick-Start-(om.next)#components-with-queries--mutations

Snippets:

`#js`:

```
(defui Counter
  static om/IQuery
  (query [this]
    [:count])
  Object
  (render [this]
    (let [{:keys [count]} (om/props this)]
      (dom/div nil
        (dom/span nil (str "Count: " count))
        (dom/button
          #js {:onClick
               (fn [e] (om/transact! this '[(increment)]))}
          "Click me!")))))
```

`#uuid`:

```
(om/from-history reconciler
  #uuid "9e7160a0-89cc-4482-aba1-7b894a1c54b4")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commonly found in EDN and ClojureScript this use of # is called the **tagged literal**. Look at this example,

```
user=> (java.util.Date.)
#inst "2014-05-19T19:12:37.925-00:00"
```

When we create a new date it is represented as a tagged literal, or in this case a tagged string. We can use Clojures read-string to read this back (or use it directly)

```
user=> (type #inst "2014-05-19T19:12:37.925-00:00")
java.util.Date
(read-string "#inst \"2014-05-19T19:12:37.925-00:00\"")
#inst "2014-05-19T19:12:37.925-00:00"
user=> (type (read-string "#inst \"2014-05-19T19:12:37.925-00:00\""))
java.util.Date
```

A tagged literal tells the reader how to parse the literal value. Other common uses include #uuid for generating UUIDs and in the ClojureScript world an extremely common use of tagged literals is #js which can be used to convert ClojureScript data structures into JavaScript structures directly.

Courtesy: [The Weird and Wonderful Characters of Clojure](https://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/)